# Filter Firebase data Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load every image of type Modern on Firebase with Swift. How can I do it?

**Here's my data model:**

```
"arts" : {
    "-KW5plrmDFMGa9pUlTg3" : {
   "description" : "Title ",
   "height" : 25.36023,
   "imageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/medici-b6f69.appspot.com/o/Arts%2FJ7U039FN6YckdbQ7KgeJKuZDO2I3%2F26DDC192-C081-4588-BD52-2841FA3EF507?alt=media&token=e828936c-5341-4429-94e9-c3aefa81769b",
   "postDate" : 1478657252917,
   "title" : "Title ",
   "type" : "Modern",
   "width" : 25.99424
}
```

Here's what I tried. But it's not working.

```
DataBase.child("arts").queryOrdered(byChild: "Modern").observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    self.posts = []

    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")

        for snap in snapshot {
            if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                let key = snap.key
                let post = ProfileArtModel(key: key, artData: postDict)
                self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
            }
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Please post full tree from fire base, i can't see arts and mordern in tree.

Comment: change (byChild: "mordern") -> (byChild: "modern")

Comment: I just edited the three @TejasArdeshna. It still won't work Sasha. Thanks

Comment: `Modern` is the actual value and not a node in your tree..You need to do `queryOrdered(byChild: "type")` instead. Since you just need 'Modern', you can attach `queryEqual(toValue: "Modern")` to the query as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:-

```
DataBase.child("arts").queryOrdered(byChild: "type").queryEqual(toValue : "Modern").observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
self.posts = []

if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")

    for snap in snapshot {
        if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            let key = snap.key
            let post = ProfileArtModel(key: key, artData: postDict)
            self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your `queryOrdered` is in wrong format. Also you are always `inserting` an object into your `self.posts` array at **0 index**, so your array is always replacing an object of **0 position**. So you can modify your code as below:

  ```
  self.posts = []
  DataBase.child("arts").queryOrdered(byChild: "type").queryEqual(toValue : "Modern").observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
      if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
          print("SNAPSHOT: \(snapshot)")
          for snap in snapshot {
              if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                 let key = snap.key
                 let post = ProfileArtModel(key: key, artData: postDict) 
                 self.posts.append(post)           
              }
          }
          self.tableView.reloadData()               
      }
  }
  ```